# User interface in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am starting to learn codeigniter.I have a question:

I have an sql table called bank_account, and one of the column is bank balance. 
I want to create an agregation query of the bank balance in codeigniter.

Controller = bank_query_controller
[image]

Model = bank_query_model
[image]

View = bank_query_view
[image]

In this case, I just query the sum of the bank balance. Can anyone help me on how to create a user interface, so that the user can choose whether to query SUM, AVG, or MAX?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you should use select option tag for that.

Comment: Post the code not the image of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your view

```
<form method="post">
     <label>Type :</label>
     <select name="rType">
        <option></option>
        <option value="sum">SUM</option>
        <option value="avg">AVG</option>
        <option value="max">MAX</option>
     </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Fetch">
 </form>
```

in controller

```
$this->load->model("bank_query_model");
$rType = $this->input->post('rType');

$data["fetch_data"] = null;
if($rType){
   $data["fetch_data"] = $this->bank_query_model->fetch_data($rType);
}
$this->load->view("bank_query_view", $data);
```

in model

```
function fetch_data($rType)
{
    if($rType == 'SUM'){
        $this->db->select("SUM(bank_balance) AS Bank_Balance");
        $this->db->from("bank_account");
        $query = $this->db->get();
    }
    elseif($rType == 'AVG'){
        // Your query
        $query = '';
    }else{/*MAX*/
        // Your query
        $query = '';
    }

    return $query;
}
```